# Detect when user stopped / paused typing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I've dug around stackoverflow and found the solution which I converted to Swift, it doesn't seem to work and the selector is still being performed.

```
 func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    self.filter.searchTerm = self.searchBar.text

    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(self, selector: "getHints", object: nil)
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "getHints", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in swift? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**UPDATE 2016/09/01:**

We can use `NSTimers` or (since swift 2.0) NSObject's `performSelector` and friends.

### Aproach 1 : `performSelector`

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(
        withTarget: self,
        selector: #selector(ViewController.getHintsFromTextField),
        object: textField)
    self.perform(
        #selector(ViewController.getHintsFromTextField),
        with: textField,
        afterDelay: 0.5)
    return true
}

func getHintsFromTextField(textField: UITextField) {
    print("Hints for textField: \(textField)")
}
```

### Approach 2: `NSTimer`

```
var timer: NSTimer? = nil

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: 0.5,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(ViewController.getHints),
        userInfo: ["textField": textField],
        repeats: false)
    return true
}

func getHints(timer: Timer) {
    var userInfo = timer.userInfo as! [String: UITextField]
    print("Hints for textField: \(userInfo["textField"])")
}
```

Note I am passing the `textField` to delayed functions. It is not always required but it could make your life easier when `textField` is not easy to access or when dealing with various text fields.

#### How `NSTimer` approach is different from `performSelector`?

When you call `performSelector` the target ***is*** retained (in swift the target is always `self`) but when you use `NSTimer` the target ***is NOT*** retained. This means, if you use `NSTimer`s, you have to make sure target (in this case `self`) is alive by the time the timer fires. Otherwise the a crash will occur.

(BTW: `performSelector` uses `NSTimer` internally  )

If you are interested in GCD timers this gist a good place start:
[maicki/TimerWithGCD.md](https://gist.github.com/maicki/7622108)

Comment: Good solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer because `var userInfo = timer.userInfo as! [String: UITextField]` gets you the info for both the text from the textField but also the textField itself! Exactly what I needed :)